# Powershell - getting the scriptname of calling script in dot-sourced function

Tags: powershell

is there any way to get the scriptname of the calling script into a dot-sourced ps1 script?
This would be awsome for logging.

eg: script test1.ps1 is calling a function from dot-sourced log.ps1.

The String "test.ps1" is needed in log.ps1. Is this possible?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Another interesting question is if I could use the $args variable from the "motherscript" in the dot-sourced script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dot sourcing `log.ps1` then the execution is still occurring within `Test.ps1`.

To get the name of the executing script use:

```
$ExecutingScript = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
# Test.ps1
```

You can then use `$ExecutingScript` in whatever logging functions provided by the dot sourced script.

If you need the entire path to the executing script, you would use:

```
$MyInvocation.InvocationName
# C:\Whereever\Test.ps1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
$a = Split-Path $PSCommandPath -Leaf
```

Comment: This works even when you do a call from a function unlike accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve similar or maybe same problem - how to generate log file name based on script name. Solution from @SomeShinyObject is nice but when you have your logging script sourced from file, that is sourced from another file, then you have problem. I have arrived at following solution. In case anyone is interested.

```
$scriptFileName = Get-Item (Get-PSCallStack)[(Get-PSCallStack).length-1].ScriptName
$log = "$($scriptFileName.DirectoryName)\log\$($scriptFileName.Basename).log"
```

It basically gets highest frame from the call stack by first getting stack depth using `(Get-PSCallStack).length` then it uses this value in obtaining the frame itself and gets ScriptName from there, which is uppermost script in calling hierarchy.